# Delete all the data from the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement a button on a web page which deletes all the data that has been shown on the gridview. Is there any simpler way to delete all data at once with the button?

Comment: Not that it matters much with the amount of code you posted, but VS2015 is an `IDE`, not a `Framework` version.

Comment: I've removed the Visual Studio 2015 tag as this question is coding-related, not specific to VS.

Comment: We need your code. How do we know if there is a simpler way to do things if you post no code to compare it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to do. Just iterate over each row in the gridview with and get the primary key value, then using the sql query to delete the record from the database.
The code here can help you. I am using the NorthWind sample database.

```
void loaddata()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(datatable);
            GridView1.DataSource = datatable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int employee_id;

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                employee_id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text);
                command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeID = '" + employee_id + "'";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        loaddata();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just set the DataSource to null.

```
someGridView.DataSource = null;
someGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: I want to delete it when the button is clicked... and the data should also be deleted from the database which is a server-based database.

Comment: @Som - also deleting the data in the backend is quite a different question than you've asked...

Answer (score 0):

I can only be as vague as the question and I still don't quite understand why I can't leave comments, but I can leave an answer...

Anyway, we don't know what you're using to access your database or the model backing the GridView.

Let's say for instance you have the following class backing your GridView (the type of data your GridView consists of that you've set the Datasource to):

```
public class MyData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

In your ASPX you'd have the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" OnClick="DeleteButton_Click"/>
```

And then in your code-behind, you'd do something like this...

```
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gridViewItemsToDelete = (IEnumerable<MyData>)GridView.DataSource;

    foreach (var idToDelete in gridViewItemsToDelete.Select(r=>r.ID))
    {
        // Delete the item by its ID
        // I don't know what you're using to access your database
    }

    // Save Changes if you didn't in the foreach loop...
}
```